# How to push_back to subvector?

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I have a `vector< vector<string> >` and want to add a string to the inside vector with `push_back()`. This is what I tried:

```
vector< vector<string> > sorted_word_vecs;
char word_read[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];


for(int i = 0; i < num_of_pipes; i++)
{
    while (fgets(word_read, MAX_WORD_LENGTH, pipe_read_from_sort[i]) != NULL)
    {
        word = word_read;
        sorted_word_vecs[i].push_back(word);
    }
}
```

But I always get a seg fault (I've narrowed it down to the push_back line with cout's).  Is this the wrong way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create space in the outer vector:

```
vector< vector<string> > sorted_word_vecs;
char word_read[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
sorted_word_vecs.resize(num_of_pipes);
```

Not doing this means that you are asking for an element that doesn't exist with the `sorted_words_vecs[i`].

Answer (score 1):

You must push vector first into main vector.

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_of_pipes; i++)
{
    sorted_word_vecs.push_back(vector<string>());
    while (fgets(word_read, MAX_WORD_LENGTH, pipe_read_from_sort[i]) != NULL)
    {
        word = word_read;
        sorted_word_vecs[i].push_back(word);
    }
}
```

> (I've narrowed it down to the push_back line with cout's).

You should learn how to use debugger.

Comment: Any you should not use `new`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Before you can do anything to `sorted_word_vecs[i]`, you need to add `vector<string>` at position `i`. You can do this by resizing the vector (preferred), or by calling `sorted_word_vecs.push_back(vector<string>());`